# Column value combinations with multiple constraints based on column header

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two columns such as:

```
Name : Alex, Mohan, Rex

City : Delhi, Chennai, Mumbai, Kolkata
```

Constraint:
(if Name = Mohan then City = Chennai) or (if name = REX than City = Mumbai)

Output:

```
[(Alex,Delhi),(Alex,Chennai),(Alex,Mumbai),(Alex,Kolkata),(Mohan,Chennai),(Rex, Mumbai)]
```

Normal combination, I am able to generate which would be 12 but after apply constraint I am not able to. Please suggest your solutions.

Comment: I really do not get the question here. Do you want all possible combinations? Only combinations where `City == Chennai` ?

Comment: okay, let me help you.... Like alex has four combinations((Alex,Delhi),(Alex,Chennai),(Alex,Mumbai),(Alex,Kolkata)) Mohan will also generate same four combination ((Mohan,Delhi),(Mohan,Chennai),(Mohan,Mumbai),(Mohan,Kolkata)) But due to the constraint of  (if Name = Mohan then City = Chennai) only one value of combination will generate which is (Mohan, Chennai). Same for other condition as well. So I have input and Constraints, I want to generate the output which I have mentioned in question.

Comment: Make a dict of constraints. If the name does not have a constraint (check in dict), then just combine it with the various cities.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a cross join then filter out your rows manually.

assuming your dataframe looks like this

```
     name      city
0    Alex     Delhi
1   Mohan   Chennai
2     Rex    Mumbai
3     NaN   Kolkata

df2 = pd.merge(
df[['city']].assign(key='key'),
df[['name']].dropna().assign(key='key'),
on='key',how='outer'
).drop('key',axis=1)


mohan = df2[(df2['name'] == 'Mohan') & (df2['city'] == 'Chennai')].index
rex = df2[(df2['name'] == 'Rex') & (df2['city'] == 'Mumbai')].index

df3 = pd.concat([df2.iloc[mohan|rex],df2[~df2['name'].isin(['Mohan','Rex'])]])

print(list(df3.itertuples(index=None,name=None)))



[('Chennai', 'Mohan'),
 ('Mumbai', 'Rex'),
 ('Delhi', 'Alex'),
 ('Chennai', 'Alex'),
 ('Mumbai', 'Alex'),
 ('Kolkata', 'Alex')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
names = ["Alex", "Mohan", "Rex"]
cities = ["Delhi", "Chennai", "Mumbai", "Kolkata"]
constraint = {"Mohan":"Chennai","Rex":"Mumbai"}

result = []

for name in names:
    if name in constraint:
        result.append((name,constraint[name]))
        continue
    else:
        for city in cities:
            result.append((name,city))

print(result)
```

output:

```
[('Alex', 'Delhi'), ('Alex', 'Chennai'), ('Alex', 'Mumbai'), ('Alex', 'Kolkata'), ('Mohan', 'Chennai'), ('Rex', 'Mumbai')]
```

other scenario:

```
cities = ["Delhi", "Chennai", "Mumbai", "Kolkata"]
cities_map = [1, 2, 3, 4]
dict_city = dict(zip(cities_map,cities))
result2 = []

for city_ix,city in dict_city.items():
        if city_ix >=2:
                result2.append(("Alex",city))
                continue
        else:
                for name in names:
                        if name is not "Alex":
                                result2.append((name,city))
```

Comment: Hey, Your approach is promising. But I have doubt to use same approach if delhi, chennai, mumbai, Kolkata is replace with 1,2,3,4 and my constraint would be if (City >=2 then name == Alex). I understand, this constraint is bit weird. But this question is a part of big story, I am trying to frame my best.